# How to call onEvent at a specific point in the program?

Tags: javascript, html, css, code.org

I'm creating a game that is like Dance Dance Revolution, where colored arrows move down the screen and into a grey arrow outline area, similar to this GIF

[Example Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nbNC.gif)

The core functionality of my program is stored in an onEvent, which responds when "keydown" is pressed. The onEvent checks, if the correct arrow is pressed and if that arrow pressed coincides with the spawned direction of the moving colored arrow. (code in spoiler)

```
onEvent("playScreen", "keydown", function(event) {
    if (getYPosition(shownArrow) == getYPosition("arrowsUpG")) {
      if (shownArrow === arrowList[0] && event.key == "Left" && getYPosition(shownArrow) === getYPosition("arrowsLeftG")) {
        speed(100);
        displayArrows();
      } else {
        if (shownArrow === arrowList[1] && event.key == "Right" && getYPosition(shownArrow) === getYPosition("arrowsRightG")) {
           speed(100);
           displayArrows();
        } else {
          if (shownArrow === arrowList[2] && event.key == "Down" && getYPosition(shownArrow) === getYPosition("arrowsDownG")) {
             speed(100);
             displayArrows();
          } else {
            if (shownArrow === arrowList[3] && event.key == "Up" && getYPosition(shownArrow) === getYPosition("arrowsUpG")) {
               speed(100);
               displayArrows();
            } else {
              healthDanger();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

- shownArrow - colored arrow that moves down the screen (1
  spawns at a time).
- displayArrows - updates the game score, hides
  the shownArrow, then generates and shows a new one (under the same
  variable name). This new arrow is then repositioned at the top of the
  screen so the game can progress
- healthDanger - lowers the
  health, if the conditions are not met.

I attempted to add an if statement right after the onEvent that checks for position, but it does not work as intended.

The game can progress, however, if the correct arrow is pressed BEFORE it reaches the empty arrow outlines, then the score still increments. I tried making the onEvent into a function, so it  that it can only be called once,when  the arrow is done moving down the screen (until it reaches the outline position), however, the keypress still gets registered and added to the score, so I removed it.

Here is the function that makes the arrow move down the screen:

```
function movingArrows() {
  speed(99.999999999999);
  while (getYPosition(shownArrow) !== getYPosition("arrowsUpG")) {
    setPosition(shownArrow, getXPosition(shownArrow), getYPosition(shownArrow) + 1);
    console.log(getYPosition(shownArrow));
  }
//healthDanger();
}
```

- arrowsUpG- is the Y position of the entire right, left, up, down arrow outlines (they are all the same Y position)
- speed 99.99999 - is used so the arrow is able to slide down the screen, I will clean that up later.(the arrows keep moving down the screen until they reach the outline. Once they do, the onEvent is able to be registered
  because Java is freed from the while-loop)

  - ignore healthDanger, thats a WIP function that will decrease a health variable

**QUESTION**
 how can I make it so an onEvent can be called at a specific time, if that is even possible? I do not want the onEvent to activate before the falling arrows reach the outline, as that increases the score when it is not supposed to.

Also I apologize for any incorrect Java Implementation. I am taking an intro class in Java that uses a site called code.org, and I am very new to coding, also this is my final project.

Thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are checking just for exact pixel. You don't consider that your game is running on various FPS's and that your arrow may skip a frame or two. I would add some range in which if you press key it would count as a correct (think of it as a hitbox). It would be okay to allow it in range edge + half of arrow size.

So it would be something like:

```
onEvent("playScreen", "keydown", function(event) {
    if (getYPosition(shownArrow) == getYPosition("arrowsUpG")) {
      if (shownArrow === arrowList[0] && event.key == "Left" && getYPosition(shownArrow) >= playScreen.height - shownArrow.height/2 && getYPosition(shownArrow) <= playScreen.height ) {
      // you clicked at right time, do something
      }
    }
});
```

Edit: Code up would be if your arrows are moving from top to the bottom. If your arrows are going from bottom to the top it would be something like:

```
onEvent("playScreen", "keydown", function(event) {
    if (getYPosition(shownArrow) == getYPosition("arrowsUpG")) {
      if (shownArrow === arrowList[0] && event.key == "Left" && getYPosition(shownArrow) >= 0 && getYPosition(shownArrow) <= 0 + shownArrow.height) {
      // you clicked at right time, do something
      }
    }
});
```